# XPath get rid of line breaks when extracting text

Tags: r, xpath

What is the best way to get rid of newlines in next example:

Text:

```
<p>Le danger vient également des redoutés services de sécurité, auxquels de nombreuses exactions sont imputées durant les 23 ans du régime Ben Ali, et de l'élite corrompue qui contrôle encore des secteurs entiers de l'économie, a estimé Richmaoui, qui dirige la section "<em>Etat de droit</em>" du HCR.&nbsp;</p>
```

I'm using XPath:

```
//p//text()[normalize-space()]|//h3//text()[normalize-space()]
```

Result:

```
Le danger vient également des redoutés services de sécurité, auxquels de nombreuses exactions sont imputées durant les 23 ans du régime Ben Ali, et de l'élite corrompue qui contrôle encore des secteurs entiers de l'économie, a estimé Richmaoui, qui dirige la section " 


Etat de droit 

" du HCR.
```

I need the same result but without line breaks:

```
     Le danger vient également des redoutés services de sécurité, auxquels de nombreuses exactions sont imputées durant les 23 ans du régime Ben Ali, et de l'élite corrompue qui contrôle encore des secteurs entiers de l'économie, a estimé Richmaoui, qui dirige la section "Etat de droit" du HCR.
```

**UPD**

Managed to do it with one command in R:

```
xpathSApply(url.html, "//p[normalize-space()]|//h3[normalize-space()]", xmlValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed that there is always only one element matches the XPath at a time, then you can modify the XPath a bit to return the element that hold the entire text nodes (the `<p>` element in the sample markup above) wrapped in `normalize-space()` function :

```
normalize-space(//p[text()[normalize-space()]])
```

...otherwise this can't be achieved using pure XPath 1.0 expression

**demo link :** http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/dd6fc2aaf1e8c86e283128ab777033c0

**output :**

> Le danger vient également des redoutés services de sécurité, auxquels de nombreuses exactions sont imputées durant les 23 ans du régime Ben Ali, et de l'élite corrompue qui contrôle encore des secteurs entiers de l'économie, a estimé Richmaoui, qui dirige la section "Etat de droit" du HCR.